# Track user new downloads and updated on App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I know I can check sales & trends using itunes Connect. is the figure there only for new downloads or for users that updates the app as well ? How to know users new users (new download) or existing user (update app) ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to sales and trends at ItunesConnect.

At the top, there's Add Filters. From Filters drop down, you will see "Transaction Type".

When you click it, it will show all the categories, Free, Paid, Updates, Redownload etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use new feature on ITC for this:

> Go to ITC -> App Analytics -> select_app -> Metrics -> Paying users

It will show the users data in a particular date range.